# Maven run/debug configurations in Intellij

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I have been using eclipse for some long time. I have previously decided to switch to intellij. There is however a feature in eclipse that I miss. When using maven, I used to have a maven clean install run config saved under my run configs. And have the base directory as ${project_loc}.

[image]

Thus when i select the project from the project explorer, I can run the maven config on it. I have found in intellij the create/run configuration dialog which has the working directory field.

My question is how can i configure this field to get the same effect as eclipse's ${project_loc} variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is something [Maven Helper plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179?pr=idea) solves. It runs goals for the selected module.